# How to get updated value for isolated scope using angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml, angularjs-directive

i have a directive that is making xml pretty for browser when first time page loads it gets the `string` value. but when value change dynamically `string` is  not being updated `xml` remain same. Any idea what is implemented wrong in below directive to get updated value of `xml` ?

html

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2default"><pre class="prettyprint lang-xml" xml="{{string}}"></pre></div>
```

directive.js

```
angular.module('angularModelerApp').directive('prettyprint', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    scope: {
      xml: '@'
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.text(vkbeautify.xml(scope.xml, 4));
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link function is only executed once when the directive is first inserted into the DOM.  Therefore Angular only gets the initial value of scope.xml in your code, and is not subscribing to updates.

You probably want something like:

```
angular.module('angularModelerApp').directive('prettyprint',       function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    scope: {
      xml: '@'
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('xml', function(newVal, oldVal) {
         element.text(vkbeautify.xml(newVal, 4));
      });
    }
  };
});
```

For more details see the section on $watch in the documentation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope